# SQL: Selecting the lowest value row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at hospital claims data and there are multiple rows with the same admission date. I only want one admission date per patient. If there are multiple rows with the same admission date, I want to select the row with the largest LOS, or when LOS are equal, I want to select the one with the oldest admission date. For example, given the following data:

```
ID     ADMIT     DC      LOS  CLMID
--     -----     --      ---  -----
1      1-1-07    1-1-07   0    XXX
1      1-2-07    1-2-07   0    XXX
2      1-5-07    1-10-07  5    YYY
3      2-8-07    2-8-07   0    ZZZ
3      2-8-07    2-12-07  4    ZZZ
3      2-8-07    2-10-07  2    ZZZ
```

I would want to select:

```
ID     ADMIT     DC      LOS   CLMID
--     -----     --      ---   -----
1      1-1-07    1-1-07   0     XXX
2      1-5-07    1-10-07  5     YYY
3      2-8-07    2-12-07  4     ZZZ
```

I've tried using the MIN aggregrate function, but I'm pretty lost on how to get where I want. I'm new to SQL and would appreciate any help!

So far, this is my best shot:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ID, ADMIT, DC, LOS, CLMID, MIN(ADMIT)

FROM
   TABLE1

GROUP BY
   ID, ADMIT, DC, LOS, CLMID

ORDER BY
   ID
```

I've also tried just selecting just the maximum LOS instead of the minimum admit, but that doesn't do it either.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: Post your best shot in solving your problem.

Comment: I apologize--it's SQL Server. I'm so new ><

Answer (score 1):

This is a prioritization and you can solve these problems with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by admit asc, los desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

A couple of notes:

- I assume that dates are actually stored as date/times in the database and not as strings.
- The conditions in your first paragraph are a bit vague.  This gets the one row for each patient withi the highest `los` on the earliest `admit` date.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL this would be something like:

```
Select distinct ID, * from admissions_table order by DC DESC group by ID
```

Comment: Did you look at the desired output?